# What are possible solution or script that can be used for server crash detection and trigger procedures?

Tags: node.js, nginx, exception, ubuntu-server

I'm developing on the same server where I host some webpages, in this case with Ajenti, nginx and node.js installed on a Ubuntu Server, and I noticed that when I crash the server in a test, I need to log in to ajenti or ssh and restart the webpages.

This made me wonder if nginx or Ubuntu can detect such a crash like a `502 Bad Gateway Error` and if there is also a command or tool to restart the webpages?

With this I could probably script it all up and get the webpages restarted, automatically, every time I do something to crash the server.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use something like [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) which can (among many other things) check for (and optionally restart) crashed processes.

Comment: Hey I have already [Ajenti installed](http://ajenti.org/), can monit be installed alongside this? Because it's also a web server monitor...

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't be used alongside it. It may not integrate into Ajenti unless someone has written a monit plugin or something, otherwise you can use monit from the command line or its bundled web interface.

Comment: Well, it looks nice but I'm not looking for another monitor, I'm looking for an automated way to detect a crash and using that to immediately restart the website.